# How to import a file in REDCap using MATLAB web services

Tags: matlab, rest, redcap

I cannot file a way to upload a file in REDCAP using [MATLAB web services](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/internet-file-access.html).  While this is possible using `curl` (see below), REDCAP API
is a REST API and the documentation for "Import file" says it it should support a POST request, I am
unable to find how to use MATLAB `webwrite` for this purpose.

Here is a code snippet:

```
url = 'xxxxx';      % REDCap API
token = 'xxxxxx';   % REDCap token
filename = 'xxxxx'; % filename
record = '1';
field = 'file';

% read file content
fid = fopen(filename, 'rb');
if fid==-1 
    error(['Cannot open ' filename])
end
data = char(fread(fid));
fclose(fid);

ops = weboptions('CertificateFilename', '', 'Debug', false);

result = webwrite(url, 'token', token, ...
        'content','file', ...
        'action', 'import', ...
        'record', record,... 
        'field', field, ...
        'file', data, ...
        'returnFormat','csv', ops);
```

For the `file` parameter, REDCap API documentations says it corresponds to the "content of the file",
without saying how it must be formatted. I have also tried to use the filename instead of the file content because I have found that other implementations based on `curl` use the filename as parameter
(see below) but it did not work.

The response I get from REDCAP when using the above code is

```
The server returned the status 403 with message
"Forbidden" in response to the request to URL
http://172.17.210.219/redcap/redcap/api/.
```

which suggests that it might be a lack of privilege but I don't have problems uploading a file using a difference interface.

The following examples work but they rely on `curl` internally or externally:

```
url <- "http://172.17.210.219/redcap/redcap/api/"
file <- 'contents.m'
formData <- list("token"=token,
    action='import',
    content='file',
    record='1',
    field='file',
    event='',
    returnFormat='json',
    file=httr::upload_file(file)
)
response <- httr::POST(url, body = formData, encode = "multipart")
result <- httr::content(response)
```

`httr::POST` relies on `curl` package, which is an interface to `libcurl` C library.

Similarly, a function in  [Matlab REDCap API](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/101809-redcap-interface) interface also uses 'curl' which must be installed on the machine:

```
dToken = [  ...
    '-F "token=', redcap_token, '"', ...
    ' -F "content=file"', ...
    ' -F "action=import"', ...
    ' -F "record=', record_num, '"', ...
    ' -F "event=', varargin{3}, '"', ...
    ' -F "field=', varargin{4}, '"', ...
    ' -F "filename=', [this_name, this_ext], '"', ...
    ' -F "file=@', temp, '"'];                    
unixCmd = ['curl  ', hCmd2, '  -X POST  ', hCmd2, '  ', dToken, '  ', redcap_url]; 
[uState, uResultUpload] = system( unixCmd );  % for PC
```

In both cases, `curl` takes the filename as argument and not the file content.   Also, `curl` seems to be able to be able to send the filename
in addition to the file content to REDCap.